# can we return different class objects using if else in JAVA?

Tags: java

I was writing an automation test for a web page in which one step is common for different authentication class and after clicking next button the second step changes for each authentication class.

Common class for selecting authentication class:

```
class CreateClassStep1 {
    ///some code
    public ? nextButton() {
        nexbutton.click()
    }
}
```

Now suppose there are four authentication classes `A`,`B`,`C` and `D`.The function should return according to the authentication class selected.

So how is it possible? Is it possible to return different type of objects using `if-else`?

Comment: through a common parent class (Object, for instance), but then you would need to cast it back in the receiving method

Comment: It is possible through inheritance, i.e. `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` have to `extends` from a common `ParentClass`. Note that all classes implicitly `extends Object`, but I would advice you to not return an instance of type `Object` since you would have to downcast the instance.

Comment: A common `class` or `interface` allows you that. Only the member/method of that common type will be known and a cast will be needed to us specific method.

Answer (score 1):

Just using a common interface or class, you can then return and then access the methods of that common type no matter the instance type (it will be a subclass of that type)

A common interface

```
public interface I{
    public String getName();
}
```

Here a two implementation of that common interface :

```
public class A implements I{
    public String getName(){ return "A"; }
}

public class B implements I{
    public String getName(){ return "B"; }
    public String otherMethod(){ return "otherValue"; }
}
```

Let's create a simple `Test` class that will hold our main method for the test with a method that return one of the implementation :

```
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){ ... }

    //return a `I` type
    public static I getInstance(int i){
        if(i == 0){
            return new A();
        }else{
            return new B();
        }
    }
}
```

Some test could look like :

```
I i;
i = getInstance(0); //type A
i.getName(); //A

i = getInstance(1); //type B
i.getName(); //B
```

This could be inlined like :

```
getInstance(0).getName(); //A
getInstance(1).getName(); //B
```

Now, about the visibility of the method, you can't access a method not define in the variable type. Here the variable `i` is declared as a `I`, so you only have a method `getName()`, even if an instance of `B` is stored in it :

```
i.otherMethod(); //COMPILE ERROR unknown method
```

You need to cast the instance :

```
B b = (B) i;
b.otherMethod(); //otherValue
```

But this is unsafe, you can't cast A into B, so it could throw an exception at runtime.

FYI: I used an interface because all I need here is some methods declaration (`getName`). You can used a class if you want (or abstract class) to extends, but know that one class can only extends one super class. This can be a problem if you need to inherit from another class.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Stat` interface, then create each State class to implement the `next` method. After that you can use a global variable to record current state.

```
interface State {
    State next();
}
```

Every time you need to go to next state, just call

```
currentState = currentState.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following ways

1. By extending class A,B,C and D with a new Parent class/interface and make return type as that Parent class.
2. By making return type as Object
3. By using [generics](https://juristr.com/blog/2008/03/java-generics-c-class-templates-vs-java/)

For all these ways, at receiving end you have to typecast the return type to correct Class. For that, you can take help of [instanceOf](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator)

Comment: In that context, I prefer to use an interface, since Java doesn't allow to extends more than one class, at least that common type won't be a problem if you need to extends another class later (and you don't really need any members in that common class/interface)

Comment: Yeah, that will work!. It's up to you. It depends on the design of your code and requirement. I just gave you options.